# Calling a gif with createimagefromgif in PHP

Tags: php, html, image, imageview, gif

I've been trying to display a gif image using PHP and have not found a solution to my problem with the research I've done. I know I can display image in HTML/CSS, but I need to use php in this case.

```
<html>
    <?php
        $img = imagecreatefromgif("http://www.mysite.com/images/timer.gif");
    ?>

        <img src="<?= $img ?>" alt="timer" />

</html>
```

That code resides in a php doc on my server. I can tell the code is working because an icon of a torn image displays on my site, and when I attempt to save the torn icon image to desktop, the automatic file name appears as "Resource id.html"?

I read somewhere that creating gifs with Photoshop CS5 (as I did) uses a different frame separator sequence, **\x00\x21**, instead of the official standard **\x00\x2C**. The guy then said he uses pattern **"#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00(\x2C|\x21)#s"** to bypass that issue but I have no idea how/where to implement that or if that is even my issue (tried a different gif from internet and had same display problem). Thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagecreatefromgif() returns an image resource, which you can't use in this way.

Have your PHP script output the image data, with the correct headers (see example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php).

Then you can call your script just like you would any other image:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/generate_image.php" alt="timer" />
```

Comment: Billy, thanks for getting back to me. Still not working though... I'm using the exact example at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php and I'm pulling the same broken image icon.